# ".cancel()" function of Kivy.Clock doesn't work?

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy, clock

I have currently a problem regarding the **"Clock"** library of the framework

**"Kivy"**. I am creating a Clock-Thread and want to terminate/cancel it but it does not seem to work.

I already read the documentation of Kivy.Clock function and did the same like them.

[The link to the Kivy.Clock function](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html)

My Code:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        Window.size = (1280, 720)

        ev1 = Clock.schedule_interval(self.print_func, 1)
        ev1.cancel()

    def print_func(self, dt = None):
        print ("Test")
```

Imagine that a .kv file exist and that the MainWindow class is getting called. Everything works fine, except of the canceling of the Clock interval.

Expected result should be that the Clock-Thread should be terminated or rather set to inactive.

Actual result is that it has no effect and the Clock-Thread is still running.

EDIT: I got this function of Clock to work..

I found out that the .cancel() and .unschedule() functions for Clock.schedule_interval() don‘t work. I created then a trigger: Clock.create_trigger() and tried it with .cancel() and .unschedule(). These both functions worked perfectly.

Comment: Your code can't be run because `self` is not defined outside of a class. Please update your example.

Comment: I did update it ^^

Comment: Did you try to run it? Because now you're not in a class scope and defining `print_func` after calling results with `NameError: name 'print_func' is not defined`.

Comment: True... wait i will edit it with the class enviroment

Comment: @Nykakin I updated the code. I tested it and it works except, like i mentioned, the cancel function of Clock.

Comment: have you tried `Clock.unschedule(self.print_func)` instead of `.cancel()`?

Comment: Your code works correctly for me (after adding an `App` class and running it). I don't see any `Clock-Thread` running at all. Where are you seeing `Clock-Thread`?

Comment: Try `.unschedule()`

Comment: Thanks guys for the tips! I got it to work. I will edit my question to help others in the future.

Comment: If unschedule and cancel don't work, it's a bug (or two) in kivy, if so, please report with a reproducible example, but i'd be surprised, as i've used unschedule on schedule_interval events a *lot* without issues, cancel should work too, and should be more efficient, as it avoids traversing the list of events to find the one to cancel. - edit, the code works correctly here, nothing is print unless i remove the call to cancel.